# Representations of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

In Corollary 7.2 of http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Bosshardt.pdf, why is the set of weights an *unbroken* string? I understand we get a finite number of weights by looking at the invariant subspace $$W = \bigoplus\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} V_{\lambda+2k}$$ where $\lambda$ is a fixed weight, but I don't understand why it is *unbroken*.

I mean, why can't we have something like:

\begin{align*} 
   V_{\lambda-2m_1} & \neq 0 \\
   V_{\lambda} &= 0 \\
   V_{\lambda+2m_2} & \neq 0
\end{align*}

where $m_1,m_2 \geq 1$?

Comment: In that case, the module would not be irreducible.

Comment: I don't see why. If $V_\lambda=0$, then keeping it in the sum or not has no effect. How does one get an invariant subspace if the string is broken? I'm not saying you're lying, I'm just confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mariano says, we assume that the representation is irreducible.  If $V_\lambda = 0$ then $V = A \oplus B$ where
$$A = \sum_{\lambda_1 > 0}V_{\lambda - 2\lambda_1}$$
and
$$B = \sum_{\lambda_1 > 0}V_{\lambda + 2\lambda_1}.$$
Observe that this is certainly a direct sum of vector spaces.  Each space is a sum of weight spaces so it's invariant under the action of $h$.  The actions of $x$ and $y$ act on weight vectors by sending them to weight vectors of weight exactly $2$ higher (in the case of $x$) or $2$ lower (in the case of $y$).  Thus it's obvious that $A$ is closed under the action of $y$ and $B$ is closed under the action of $x$.  Finally note that $A$ is closed under the action of $x$ because $xV_{\lambda - 2\lambda_1} = V_{\lambda - 2(\lambda_1 - 1)}$ and either $\lambda_1 - 1 > 0$, making $V_{\lambda - 2(\lambda_1 - 1)} \subseteq A$ or $\lambda_1 - 1 = 0$, making $V_{\lambda - 2(\lambda_1 - 1)} = V_\lambda = 0$.  The same argument shows that $B$ is closed under the action of $y$.

But now, this is worse than irreducible, this is decomposable.